# How to display specific lines of text from a text file in a textbox?

Tags: c#

I have created an app that will open a file dialog, you can open a file, and then display it's contents in textbox. Howvever, there are three blocks of text from the file that I really need. I need to be able to "parse" only display these blocks of text. I have used readalllines. However, not sure how to sort via a For each loop. Any help would be appreciated:

My code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    //Setting initial directory to the automated repository
    openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "\\\\10.2.XXX.XX\\Repository\\AutomatedVersionRepository\\JMN Web Application\\";

    // Set filter options and filter index.
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|Config files (*.config*)|*.config*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    // Call the ShowDialog method to show the dialog box.
    //bool? userClickedOK = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() ==DialogResult.OK;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() ==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
       if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) !=null)
       {
           string strfilename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
           string []filetext = File.ReadAllLines(strfilename);
           foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(strfilename))
           {
              //process the line
           }
           //richTextBox1.Text = filetext;
       }
```

Example of Blocks of text:

```
 <!---Interface URLS and settings-->
<add key="IUFUploadPath" value="" />
<add key="JSDskAPIURL" value="http://api.documentation.com/16_4" />
<add key="PvAPIURL" value="http://devapi.documentation.com/16_4" />
<add key="FirstDataWebServiceURL" value="https://dev.SpectrumRetailNet.Com/PPSAPI" />
<add key="ReportServerUrl" value="https://reports64.documentation.com/9_2_0/FrameHost.aspx" />
<add key="HelpassAdminUrl" value="http://Helpppass.documentation.com/app/AdminConsole.aspx" />
<add key="XAIMAPIURL" value="//devquippe.documentation.com/ws.aspx" />
```

Comment: This looks like an xml file so you should be using xml classes which makes job much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I would use

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> settingsDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "add")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("add");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement add = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                    settingsDict.Add((string)add.Attribute("key"), (string)add.Attribute("value"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jdweng I will try your suggestion!